# Closure of unit ball in C[0,1] in integral and supreme metrics

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

Consider the set {$f \in C[0,1]: \forall t \in [0,1] -1 < f(t) <1 $}.
This is the unit ball for the supreme metric.

I want to know what is the interior and closure of this set in the supreme and integral metrics.

It's open in the uniform metric.
I think the closure in both is going to be {$f \in C[0,1]: \forall t \in [0,1] -1 \leq f(t) \leq 1 $}, but I don't know how to justify.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is open in the uniform metric. Clearly, any $f$ in its closure in the  uniform metric satisifes $-1\le f\le 1$. Conversely, if $f$ satisfies these inequalities then $(1-\frac  1n) f$ is a sequence in this set converging to $f$.

So the closure is $\{f: -1\le f\le 1\}$.

W.r.t. the integral metric this set is neither open nor closed but its closure is still $\{f: -1\le f\le 1\}$. Use the sequence $(1-\frac  1n) f$ for proving this.

Comment: Ohh I get it now, thank you so much and do you have any ideia what would be the interior of this set in the integral metric?

Comment: Its interior is empty in the integral metric. If you cannot prove this,  I will give you  a hint.  @Albi

Answer (score 0):

The question you're asking is not correct. You cannot properly define the interior and closure of a set without specifying the ambient space. This is because openness and closeness are relative notions.

For instance, in the case your considering the ambient space to be the set itself, the it is closed and open, so it's both it's interior and it's closure.

There are other ambient spaces which make somewhat sense ($L^p$ spaces and so on). I will assume that you want to know for the case where the ambient space is $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$.

For the supremum metric, the you are correct, it is an open set (it is an open ball) and it's closure is the closed ball (this is the case in a large number of metric spaces).

For the integral metric ($L^1$), the interior will be empty, indeed consider the functions $$f_n(t) = \begin{cases} n(1-tn^2)&\text{ for }t\in[0,\frac{1}{n^2}] \\0 &\text{ for } t\in [\frac{1}{n^2}, 1] \end{cases}$$ then $\|f_n\|_{L^1} = \frac{1}{2n}$ goes to zero and clearly $f_n \not\in B_{L^\infty}(0,1)$ you can then approach any function $f$ inside $B_{L^\infty}(0,1)$ by $f+f_n$.

The closure will also be $\bar{B}_{L^\infty}(0,1)$.

First lets prove that the $L^1$ closure of $B_{L^\infty}(0,1)$ is included in
$\bar{B}_{L^\infty}(0,1)$. Indeed, let $f\not \in \bar{B}_{L^\infty}(0,1)$. Then there exists $\epsilon >0$  and $x\in[0,1]$ such that $|f(x)| >1+\epsilon$, then there exists $\eta> 0$ such that $f(x)\geq \epsilon/2$ over $[x, x+\eta]$ (or $[x-\eta, x]$) and so for any function $g\in B_{L^\infty}(0,1)$ we have $\|f-g\|_{L^1} \geq \eta\epsilon/4$. Thus $f$ does not belong to the closure of $B_{L^\infty}(0,1)$.

The other inclusion comes directly from the fact that $\|f-g\|_{L_1} \leq \|f-g\|_{L^\infty}$ and so if $f\in \bar{B}_{L^\infty}(0,1)$ can be approached arbitrary close (for the supremum metric) by functions in $B_{L^\infty}(0,1)$, then they can also be approached arbitrary close by those same functions in the sense of the integral metric.